# Passing argument containing dot to a batch script

Tags: batch-file

So I'm having trouble passing an argument with a period to a batch script file.
./myScript.bat 23.97

In my script, if I do

```
arg1 = %1
echo %arg1%
```

This will display 23.97 but if I do a comparison

```
arg1 = %1
   if "%arg1%" == "23.97"
      echo %arg1%
```

then it doesn't display at the argument at all. Fyi, i'm not trying to treat it at a float number, just a normal string. I'm no sure why it doesn't work, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The top code you posted cannot possibly give the result that you describe. So it is difficult to diagnose the failing code, since we can't trust it is really represents your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, in fact, have a dot (`.`) passed to a batch file as an argument. The section of your code that is causing you issue is the syntax that you use when setting the variable and using the if statement.

---

The correct syntax for setting a variable , as described by executing `help set` on the command line, is

> Displays, sets, or removes cmd.exe environment variables.
>
> `SET [variable=[string]]`
>
> `variable`  Specifies the environment-variable name.
>     `string`  Specifies a series of characters to assign to the variable.

With this in mind, the correct way to set `arg1` to the first argument passed to your batch file is

```
set arg1=%1
```

---

Your issue with the if statement is that you are trying to add a new line after the Boolean expression and before the next statement. The correct syntax is described by `help if` as

> Performs conditional processing in batch programs.
>
> ```
> IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command 
> IF [NOT] string1==string2 command  
> IF [NOT] EXIST filename command
> ```

Your if statement could be reveised to read like this:

```
if "%arg1%"=="29.37" echo arg1
```

Comment: thank you, the syntax you mentioned is correct. But I found out my problem was that I had an extra space at the end of this statement SET arg1=%1